# Rails 4 Carrierwave + Minimagick: Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `mogrify -crop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jcrop, railscasts, minimagick

Been researching around but fail to pinpoint the problem: I am following Railscasts PRO #182 on cropping images using JCrop, Carrierwave and Minimagick. As I come to recreating image versions I am prompted the error:

> CarrierWave::ProcessingError (Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `mogrify -crop! 250x250+531+32 /tmp/mini_magick20160108-6544-1ec50pf.png` failed with error:
>   mogrify: unrecognized option `-crop!' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/4197.
>   ):
>     app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:48:in`crop'
>     app/models/course.rb:15:in `crop_image'
>     app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:12:in`update'

Can somebody help me understand what this error is indicating?

Model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  after_update :crop_image

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def crop_image
    image.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    if @course.update_attributes(course_params)
      if course_params[:image].present?
        render :crop
      else
        redirect_to @course, notice: 'Successfully updated'
      end
    end
  end

  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:title, :image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
  end
end
```

ImageUploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    process :resize_to_fit => [250, 250]
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_fit(800, 350)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!("#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the option -crop! does not exist in command mogrify. The resolution is simply changing .crop! to .crop

i.e. Within ImageUploader:

`img.crop!("#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}")` --> `img.crop("#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}")`

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue with `strip`. Only happens when images are large. 
First issue of this was in 2012 and was closed without a great solution.